# unknown operator: $search pipeline mongodb stitch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pipeline

I am trying to run a query using text operator by the new MongoDB feature stitch. I have already tried a few options, but the call responds with the following message:

> unknown operator: $search

How can I resolve this error?

I also have the text index created.

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "script_text_description_text",
    "ns" : "test.scripts",
    "weights" : {
        "description" : 1,
        "script" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

Attempt #1:

```
client.executePipeline([{
    "service": "mongodb-atlas",
    "action": "aggregate",
    "args": {
        "database": "test",
        "collection": "scripts",
        "pipeline": [{
                $match: {
                    $text: {
                        $search: "docker"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}])
```

Attempt #2:

```
db.collection('scripts').find({"$text":{"$search":'docker'}})
```

Attempt #3:

```
db.collection('scripts').aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "$text": {
            "$search": "docker"
        }
    }
}])
```

**UPDATE:**

I applied this work around.

```
import { StitchClientFactory,BSON } from 'mongodb-stitch';

let bsonRegex = new BSON.BSONRegExp(search, 'i')
        // showLoading();
        db.collection('clients').find({owner_id: client.authedId(),name:bsonRegex}).execute().then(docs => {
            funct(docs);
            // hideLoading();
        });
```

Comment: What is the schema of the documents in the collection? What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-text search in Stitch pipeline aggregate actions is currently unsupported in the Beta version of the Stitch product but we hope to support them when Stitch reaches GA (General Availability).

Answer (score 0):

2 years after, the situation is still the same, `$text` is unsupported in Stitch:

https://mongodb.canny.io/mongodb-stitch/p/full-text-search

how did you implement text search? Now MongoDB Atlas has a text search feature but it's only available on M30 clusters and larger:

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/full-text-search/?jmp=docs

Comment: I updated the original question with the workaround.